# RNA-seq StringTieデータをpythonからprepDE.pyを実行してcsv形式にする

Tags: bioinformatics

度々質問させていただきます。
RNA-seq StringTieデータをDESeq2で解析するため、Macターミナルからpython2を起動してprepde.py（発現量データをcsvに変換するためにpythonで記述されたスクリプト）を実行、csvファイルを作成できればと思っています。
にわか勉強ですが、以下のコマンドで試してみました。

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/XX/yy02/ballgown'
>>> os.chdir('/Users/XX/yy02/ballgown')
>>> prepde.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'prepde' is not defined
```

構文エラーではなく、ファイル名の定義が必要そうです。実行ファイル名の定義はどのようにしたらいいでしょうか。ご教示いただけるとたすかります。

Comment: Python2 の場合、インタラクティブモードでスクリプトファイルを読み込んで実行するには `execfile('prepde.py')` とします。もしくはシェル上で `python2 prepde.py` とします。`prepde.py` をロード・実行してからインタラクティブモードに入りたい場合は `python2 -i prepde.py` とします。

Comment: いつも教えていただいてありがとうございます！execfile('prepde.py')で実行できました。ただ、prepde.pyの中身に合わせたディレクトリ配置、複数のサンプル仕様だったりするので、環境を整えてやってみます。

Comment: execfile('prepde.py')で実行できました。metropolisさんありがとうございました。macはpython2.7がデフォルトで入っていますが、python3.7を入れてしまっていたので3.7をアンインストールしました。prepde.pyで重要なことはディレクトリやファイルの配置です。１サンプルからcsvに変換できました。どなたか参考にされてください。